# Click() method not working, no exceptions sowing in console

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have tried to execute a script in Selenium Webdriver But unable to click a button. The Click event not works when a program tries to click on button which have Dynamic ID.
I have executed my script in Google Chrome Browser. I have multiple buttons on page which contains dynamic ID.
So first i get the name of each button with the help of `getText()` method and then i tried to click on a particular button.But `Click()` method not working, no exceptions showing in console.
Here is the source code of finding and clicking the button:

```
for (int i=0; i<button.size();i++) {
WebElement local_button=button.get(i);
String value1=local_button.getText();
System.out.println("values from buttons are text=====>>>>>"+value1);
 if(value1.equalsIgnoreCase("ER Image"))
{
local_button.click();
}
}
```

Comment: Please share the URL

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit' and @value='Save Changes']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Change your xpath in above code

Comment: I have added note